# Replacing the values in a list with nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How do I replace the values in a list with nested lists?
For example:

```
array1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
array2 = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]
```

With these arrays, I need to replace all the values of array1 with the values of array2. The final array will look like the following:

```
final_array = [[0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you wanted to replace `array1` sublists values by the values of `array2`, this will do what you want:

```
array1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
array2 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]

it = iter(array2)
array1 = [[next(it) for _ in sublist] for sublist in array1]
```

This works because the length of `array2` matches the sum of `array1` sublists lengths and you kind of use use `array1` as a template of list of sublists with various lenghts.

Comment: Just in case you want to avoid reassigning, you can use this: `for sublist in array1: sublist[:] = [next(it) for _ in sublist]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your real problem but here we can have a logic by just iterating and dividing them by 10

```
for i in array1:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        i[j] /= 10
```

Comment: OP's example is confusing cause the values are related like that. What they actually want to do is replace the values in `array1` with the values from `array2`.